# How to sort a group of linked nodes

Tags: java, list, sorting, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to sort a group of linked nodes in java. 
I just started programming so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
package rAymond;

public class RandomLinkLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int temp = 0;
        Listnode holder;
        Listnode start;
        Listnode a;
        Listnode b;
        Listnode c;
        Listnode d;
        Listnode e;
        Listnode end;

        start = new Listnode(5);
        a = new Listnode(10);
        b = new Listnode(0);
        c = new Listnode(3);
        d = new Listnode(4);
        e = new Listnode(100);
        end = new Listnode(20);
        holder = new Listnode(0);

        start.setNext(a);
        a.setNext(b);
        b.setNext(c);
        c.setNext(d);
        d.setNext(e);
        e.setNext(end);
        holder.setNext(start);

        while(start!=null && start.getNext()!=null){
            if((Integer)start.getData() > (Integer)start.getNext().getData()){
                temp = (Integer) start.getData();
                start.setData(start.getNext().getData());
                start.getNext().setData(temp);
            }
            start = start.getNext();
        }

        while(holder != null &&  holder.getNext()!=null){
            System.out.println(holder.getData());
            holder = holder.getNext();
        }

    }

}
```

and...

```
package rAymond;

public class Listnode {
  //*** fields ***
    private Object data;
    private Listnode next;
    private Listnode previous;

  //*** methods ***
    // 2 constructors
    public Listnode(Object d) {
    this(d, null);
    }

    public Listnode(Object d, Listnode n) {
    data = d;
    next = n;
    }

    // access to fields
    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public Listnode getPrevious(){
        return previous;
    }

    public Listnode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    // modify fields
    public void setData(Object ob) {
        data = ob;
    }

    public void setNext(Listnode n) {
        next = n;
    }

    public void setPrevious(Listnode n) {
        previous = n;
    }

    public void remove(Listnode current, Listnode parent){
        parent.setNext(current.getNext());

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The final output is: `0 5 0 3 4 10 20`

Also, is there any easier way to sort the list? Can normal array sorting techniques such as bubble sort and quick sort be applied here?

Answer (score 0):

Random access oriented sort algorithm are awkward for linked lists. A simple approach is to create an empty list, then remove nodes from the original list and insert them into the initially empty list in order.

A much faster method is to use a small array of references (or pointers) to nodes and a variation of bottom up merge sort. Wiki article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists